# .htaccess syntax code needing revision

Tags: xcode, linux, .htaccess, seo

1) i am trying to 301 all non www's to www's (including files)

**e.g.** `/subdirectory/ + /subdirectory/1.jpg` (all possibilities with the www.)

---

2) i am trying to exclude ONLY but ALL .html and .php files from showing and would like only the non trailing version to be indexed, the rest to be 301's to my domain

**e.g.** /example.html or .php >> /example

**e.g.** /example.html or .php >> to not work + to not be indexed

**e.g.** /example to ONLY work and to ONLY be indexed (to avoid duplicate content)

---

3) i am trying to 301 all dead links and 404's to my domain

**e.g.** /deadlink or /deadlink.pdf >> 301'd to my domain, example.com

---

Here is the code i currently have, however i am not sure if it's 100% proper. 
Can someone please reply with a validated syntax for these 3 tasks? Thanks.

---

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 

RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC] 

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L] 

RewriteEngine on  

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteEngine on 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f 

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule . / [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 4):

OK, you've got three parts you're trying for here, and I'll address them all separately.

Before we begin, you only need to have one

```
RewriteEngine on
```

It only needs to be turned on once.

You should also set:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

as MultiViews can otherwise cause some weird issues here.

### Redirect to WWW

Your current rules should work, but you can simplify them a little using the `!=` prefix on `RewriteCond`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=www.example.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

### Removing `.php` and `.html` suffixes

You need two separate sets of rules here: one to remove suffixes from URLs, and another to readd them internally.

Let's do the second half first, since that's easier:

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [L]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

With this in place, though, removing suffixes is a little tricky without conflicting with the rule that goes ahead and tries to put them back on. The best approach I was able to come up with was:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.(html|php)
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(html|php)$ $1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

But I'm open to suggestions.

### 301ing all dead links

Don't do that. If a link doesn't exist, it should return a page with a 404 status. If you want to redirect *visitors* to your home page from dead links, put a link in your 404 page.

Comment: Woah, thanks a lot! this did everything i needed 100% ... thanks a lot

Comment: One thing i witnessed that is occuring is... 

if i go to http://www.example.com/5.jpg (which does not exist) it goes to my custom 404 page. 

however, if i go to any .html or .php file (e.g. http://www.example.com/5.html) it still goes to my custom 404 page but addes this string to the browser bar / url ... 

http://www.example.com/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/5 

how do i fix this?

Comment: You probably need to add a `RewriteBase` directive.

Comment: When I do a "Rewrite Base /" it removed the "/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/" string but it takes you to the .html or .php without the suffix rather than remaining the same and doing a 404 return. For example, i want my "test.html" file on my webspace to be viewed by visiting the example.com/test AND I would like the url example.com/test.html or test.php to perform a 404 return HOWEVER remaining as example.com/test.html or test.php in the brower, rather than example.com/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/test OR example.com/test